# How should I interpret the random variables in this histogram?

Tags: distributions, generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, histogram

I'm currently trying to eyeball the type of distribution of this histogram to properly specify the family of distribution to use for a generalised linear model in python. I'm pretty sure it's a gamma distribution but the parameters from the model are way off. Can anyone corroborate my thoughts on if this is indeed a gamma distribution and if not why? What is a better way of approaching determining distribution of random variables?[image]

Comment: No; it's definitely not a standard gamma distribution as values of  negative and positive sign are both present. Also, choice of distribution family for a generalized linear model is not about the marginal distribution of the outcome, but about its distribution conditional on predictors. I would try viewing this on a transformed scale, such as neglog $= \text{sign}(y) \ln (1 + |y|)$. A logarithmic link even could make sense so long as you expect the mean outcome given predictors to remain positive.

Comment: You really should ask your real question about modeling, but then you need to give more background info ...